# Selenium cannot find element by ID nor xpath

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to write a script in python (3.7.3) to automate logging into a website by using Selenium for the first time. I practiced with some basic examples and went through the Selenium documentations. All good so far. But when I try it on a website of my own choice; things go wrong...

I'm managing to open up the login page, but whenever I try to get the element ID corresponding to the username field, I'm getting the *"NoSuchElementException"*, indicating that the ID-name I'm using is supposedly incorrect. I'm getting the name by looking at the HTML code by right clicking in the username-box and using the inspect function. When this is not working, I'm trying to find it through xpath, but also without success. Can anyone point out why the element is not being recognized?

**Python code**

```
from selenium import webdriver

path = r"C:\Users\path\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)

driver.get ("https://a website")
driver.find_element_by_id("login-username").send_keys(login)
driver.find_element_by_id("login-sign-in-button").click()
```

**Error message**

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="login-username"]"}
```

**HTML code of the username field:**

```
<input id="login-username" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" msd-placeholder="Username" class="margin-bottom form-control ng-pristine ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-touched" ng-model="formData.username" dh-autofocus="" required="">
```

Looking for element with xpath. I've changed the "" brackets around the id by '' to avoid errors.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='login-username']").send_keys(login)
```

And finally I tried the long xpath

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/ui-view/ui-view/div/div[1]/div[1]/ui-view/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/form/div[1]/div/input").send_keys(login)
```

I'm honestly hitting a brick wall here. It's probably not helping my knowledge of HTML is practically non existing.

**EDIT 1**
Added wait function. Code works now

```
driver.get ("https://a website")
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "login-username")))
driver.find_element_by_id("login-username").send_keys(login)
```

Comment: Your ID or xpath seems correct.Check in the DOM if there any `iframe` available?

Comment: I don't think there is an issue with the ID or Xpath. You need to wait for the webelement to get loaded completely before you can try to access it. one way is to use a hard wait (Which is not recommended) second wait is to use 'WebDriverWait' class (Explicit wait).

Comment: @Alok This seemed to be the issue. I threw in a quick and dirty time.sleep() and it worked. Cleaned up the code with a WebDriverWait as suggested.

Comment: I do wonder why this specific website needed a wait, and others, like facebook for instance, don't?

Comment: @FirminCopain all website take time between you requesting a website and the browser downloading the website. it just that some are fast and some are slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering to close this question.
As Alok pointed out, we need to wait for the webelement to get loaded completely before trying to access it.

```
driver.get ("https://a website")
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "login-username")))
driver.find_element_by_id("login-username").send_keys(login)
```